# Android app -> Java server: Google OAuth verification and security

Tags: java, security, oauth

I want my Android app users to be able to sign in with their Google account to verify who they are. I've figured out how to let them do this and obtain an access token to send to my Java server. My question is, what exactly should I do with that access token?

I've read that using the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library is encouraged, but I don't understand why. I could easily send an Http GET request to www.googleapis.com//userinfo/v2/me and manually parse the result. I only want to get the User ID, (The number id, not the email) then store it in my server or compare it to an already-stored ID. Does this open up any sort of security issues? Doing the server-side part without using the aforementioned API just seems simple enough given that I only want that small piece of information.

To summarize: Is it insecure to send an Http GET request to googleapis.com to get user info without using the official google-api-java-client library?

Answer (score 0):

Google has exposed their API through rest. Yes, you are right; there are security issues with REST. REST implements the OAuth1 and OAuth2 for security.
In OAuth architecture its mandatory that consumer (normally client, in your case your application) registers itself on the Provider (server) side and then owner (google) authenticate consumer to use its resources.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't entirely understand what you mean. My application, both client and server, would be registered with Google prior to obtaining and using the access token. And then Google would use the access token to authenticate the users of the app. This seems to fit your description, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Please notice that you can [edit] your answers. There's no need to post a second one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right to some level but you are confusing some concepts like

- Consumer (Client Application) registers itself on the provider side through request token
- After getting the request token and user authentication PROVIDER (Google) responds you with ACCESS_TOKEN
- Then ACCESS_TOKEN is used to get the resources

If you have still confusion then please visit the OAuth specifications here [OAuth Documentation](http://oauth.net/documentation/)

Comment: Alright, but why then would the method I mentioned in my original question be insecure? (Also, side note: I believe it is recommended that you respond to comments within the comments, instead of adding a new answer)

Comment: If any URI is insecure in js client then its also in java client because the authentication is managed for URI on the server side not for CLIENT (either its js/java/php or any else client). Its very rare chance that any server manages securities for clients in ROA. (In custom applications)
Note: Security level will be same either you use official google-api-java-client library or jersey/restlet/apache/js/php REST client for any URI